# JPA PersistenceContext Scope

Tags: persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a library jar which contains JPA entity classes and a service class which has an EntityManager injected into it and has methods to persist, merge etc. and uses container managed transactions.

If this jar is included in two separate wars, deployed to the same application server (JBoss EAP 6.2.0), will the same PersistenceContext be shared between the two applications?

Comment: No. The applications are isolated from each other.

Comment: Each WAR will have its own context in the app server. I believe even libraries will be load twice, one for each application, since most probably each WAR will be loaded by its own classloader instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wanted to confirm.